# not able to restore old sollet wallet (24 seed)

Tags: wallet, walletprovider, sollet.io

I got an old sollet wallet(37 accounts with sol and tokens) since beginning of sollet.io(wallet was created on sollet.io, extension came after), but cannot access it anymore, i still have the 24 recovery phrase(they are correct cuz i have them saved in many places) , i thought the derivation path is m/501'/0'/0'/0 ( deprecated one) , i run locally the extension https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/tree/master , but somehow it give me another addresses for m/501'/0'/0'/0 ( deprecated one) without funds, backpack/solflare/phantom wallet doesn't support it and give me new addresses. Any Help? Thanks

maybe related to project-serum/spl-token-wallet#42

i tried this https://twitter.com/armaniferrante/status/1594355943051264001 , still no luck.. it gives me different addresses

the peak is i also got a 12 seed created with sollet.io (not the extension) and it gives me the right addresses for m/501'/0'/0'/0 ( deprecated one) when i run the sollet extension locally , but when i do same thing with the 24 seed it only give me new addresses on m/501'/0'/0'/0 ( deprecated one)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about that, you can use `solana-keygen` to try all sorts of derivation paths to see what generates the correct pubkey, ie:

```
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?full-path=m/44/501/0/0
```

You can also write a script that tries all sorts of derivation paths until the right one is found.

Comment: hey, I've tried a lot of variants with solana-keygen , no luck till now.. what is interesting if the seed phrase has an associated passphrase(password) it generate different addresses(not sure which one I've used, tried many ofc) , someone sent me this script https://github.com/thiagosouza/crypto-wallet/blob/feature/solana/solana.wallet.ts but I'm not able yet to run it https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/pull/562

Comment: edit: i manage to run it with ts-node solana.wallet.ts , the script work as expected but still cannot find my addresses.. maybe i've saved wrong seed since beginning..

Comment: also solana-keygen recover prompt://?full-path=m/501'/0'/0/0 give me different addresses for the 12 seed(different from sollet extension), it's m/501'/0'/0'/0'